# twitter search api no results with OR

Tags: search, twitter

This suddenly stopped working, it was working, but now its not:

If I use the twitter UI and go to:

```
 https://twitter.com/#!/search/%22social%20snap%22%20OR%20%22socialsnap%22%20OR%20%22socialsnap.com%22
```

I get 7 results.

If I use the api with the same call:

```
 http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="social snap" OR "socialsnap" OR "socialsnap.com"
```

I get zero results (ran in browser to simplify test)

Im sure im being an idiot or there is some encoding issue, but im stuck...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out, I have no idea why, but this works:

```
 http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=/"social snap" OR "socialsnap" OR "socialsnap.com"
```

adding the slash after the q= makes it work...